# Show div on checkbox check and hide it when unchecked (even on load because localstorage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

So the page must show a `div` if a checkbox is checked, and hide it when it is unchecked. But I am using localstorage so it shouldn't hide on load of the page but only when it is unchecked. If it is possible, it should be usable for a lot of checkboxes (37 exactly).

**My Code:**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mob1-div" class="row hide one">Mobilisern1</div>
<div id="mob2-div" class="row hide-div">Mobilisern2</div>

<div id="mob1" class="targetDiv">Mobiliseren 1<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox chk" value="one" data-ptag="mob1-div" store="checkbox1"/></div>
<div id="mob2" class="targetDiv">Mobiliseren 2<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-ptag="mob2-div" store="checkbox2"/></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        var box = boxes[i];
        if (box.hasAttribute("store")) {
            setupBox(box);
        }
    }

    function setupBox(box) {
        var storageId = box.getAttribute("store");
        var oldVal    = localStorage.getItem(storageId);
        console.log(oldVal);
        box.checked = oldVal === "true" ? true : false;

        box.addEventListener("change", function() {
            localStorage.setItem(storageId, this.checked); 
        });
    }
});
$(function(){
$(".chk").on('change',function(){
var self=$(this);
    var aData= self.attr("value");
    $("."+aData).toggleClass('hide')
});
});
```

The problem with this code is that when you check the box the `div` shows, but if you reload the page the box is still checked. Although, the div isn't visible anymore.

Comment: `document.onload` with an `if (thing.checked || localstorage.thing.checked)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be centered around the fact that your second checkbox did not specify a `value` attribute (which all checkboxes need to have for them to make any sense).

I made a few adjustments to your code to make it more valid and compact (replaced `store` with `data-store`, used a ternary operator instead of `if/then`, combined the two `document.ready` functions into one, and changed your `for` loop to a `forEach`). These changes aren't part of the issue, but they do allow for your code to be more brief, which aids in troubleshooting.

`localStorage` doesn't work in the Stack Overflow snippets, but a working version can be seen in **[this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3mhhvyu/4/)**.